# "Name of film" versus "film's name"

Tags: difference, possessives

Is there any difference between "name of film" and "film's name"?

How can I say that I need to remember film's name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say:

> I need to remember the film's name.

or:

> I need to remember the name of **the** film.

When using the expression *name of*, what follows almost always has a article or determiner before the noun:

> I need the name of **a** good plumber.
>   I can't remember the name of **the** course.
>   I'm trying to remember the name of **your** business.
>   That's just the name of **the** game.

Although I **can** think of an exception – when the word *name* isn't referring to a title or person's name, but is instead being used to describe an abstract concept:

> They marched in the name of peace.

Of those in the original list, the first three could be written in the possessive form as well:

> I need a good plumber's name.
>   I can't remember the course's name.
>   I'm trying to remember your business's name.

However, the fourth one is tricky. If we are talking about the title of a game, such as Monopoly or chess, we can use the possessive:

> Football – that's just the game's name.

However, if we are using the [idiomatic expression](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/name+of+the+game), we must leave it in the *of* form:

> Your girlfriend dumped you? Sorry, man; that's just the name of the game.